# Mongoose: return a boolean variable if entry not present in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Can I return a boolean variable as per the conditions in a mongoose query?
Example, while getting all notification of a user, I want to show if a notification is seen by the user or not.

I have this schema:

```
const notificationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userid: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User', require: true, unique: false },
    time: Number,
    type: Number,
    seenBy: {type: [String], default: []}      // can have very large number of values (user IDs)
}, {__v: false});
```

Now while getting the notifications array I want to get an extra field which `seen` which is true if a specific user exists in respective seenBy[] array of the field.
such that I get the response object like
1 new notification
`[{userid: <someid>, time: ... <other fields> ..., seen: false}]`

Thank you

Comment: you can use `count()`, for example if count of seenBy with a conditions is zero return true else return  false

Comment: So this notification is created by one user but can be seen by many other users ? Is this correct ?

Comment: @PascalLamers right

Answer (score 3):

You would have to run an aggregation operation in which you use the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operator on two arrays i.e. the  `[userId]` and seenBy arrays which
returns true when the first array is a subset of the second, including when the first array equals the second array, and false otherwise.

The first userid array should be a string array since you will be comparing the array with another of string type so you need to convert the ObjectId to string using [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/).

As an example, the following shows the query:

```
const userId = '5ffafefe288e7a58ff08226e'; // the user id input variable as a string, could be from req.params.id or req.query.userId etc
const notifications = await Notification.aggregate([
    { '$match': { userid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } },
    { '$addFields': { 
        'seen': {
            '$setIsSubset': [
                [{ '$toString': '$userid' }],
                '$seenBy'
            ]
        }
    }}
]);
```

Comment: @chrisdam thanks for the answer, but can I perform same functionality in find() query ?

Comment: @PratikAgarwal You can't achieve the same with find, however you can do the transformation on the client side rather than the server

Comment: what kind of changes? If not, I'll have to run 2 queries. That's bad 

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
async func () {
    const doesUserExit = await User.exists({ _id: userid });
}
```

Read more [model.exists](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.exists), will return true or false.

Comment: I used that, but I need an extra variable in the query so I wont have to run a loop whether it exists or not. I want all notifications, and a "seen: false" in the ones where called userid is not present in seenBy array